PHP XAMPP Config
I try to connect my php website with a XAMPP Server so I can access my MySQL database. Any Ideas how the config has to look like, because I'm rather stuck with this one.
I tried to make a config but it didnt really work. I'll post my current config below:
<?php
    try {
        global $con;
        $server = 'localhost:3307';
        $user = 'root';
        $schema = '';

        $con = new PDO('mysql:host='.$server.';schema = '.$schema.';charset=utf8', $user);
        $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getCode().': '.$e->getMessage();
    }


Do you get any error messages? Did you look in the logs?

Xampp isn't a server, it's an installer. And it usually comes with mariadb these days rather than mysql. Your code is trying to connect to mariadb. I fixed your tags. But you forgot to tell us what the actual error/problem is. You can [edit] the rest of your post.  "Didn't really work" isn't a fixable problem. And we've no idea what your database name, username or password should be, they are all specific to you

I think missing the password param after the user. Unfortunately you didnt provide the error, but maybe your error is the blank $schema param. You wont connect to a schema, if you dont put the name of the schema in there, so you whould have to use <use [name of schema]> to connect to it.
<?php
 try
 {
     global $con;
     $server = 'localhost:3307';
     $user = 'root';
     $pwd = '';
     $schema = '';

     $con = new PDO('mysql:host='.$server.';schema = '.$schema.';charset=utf8', $user,$pwd);
     $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
 echo $e->getCode().': '.$e->getMessage();
}

